# Why does re-ordering the operands in VBA avoid "Run-time Error 6: Overflow"?

Tags: vba

I just want to know the reason for the run-time error: Overflow when running these VBA codes

```
    Function target_time(Time) As Double

       target_time = 1200 * 60 * Time

    End Function

    Sub Test()
       x = target_time(24)
       MsgBox x
    End Sub
```

I already addressed this issue by rearranging the function formula into:

```
    target_time = Time*1200 * 60
```

I just want to know why is repositioning the variable causes the runtime error overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what VBA does:

- `1200` and `60` <-- Those are small enough to be a (16-bit) `Integer`, so I'll assume they are 16-bit Integer constants.
- `1200 * 60` <-- A multiplication of two 16-bit `Integers` yields an `Integer` - there is no automatic promotion to a 32-bit `Long`. Since 1200 * 60 = 72000 exceeds the maximum value of a 16-bit integer, the expression overflows.

On the other hand, `Time * 1200` is *not* a multiplication of two 16-bit `Integers`, it's a multiplication of a "`Variant` containing an `Integer`" with an `Integer`. In this case, the result is automatically promoted to a "`Variant` containing a `Long`":

```
Dim v As Variant

v = 1200
Debug.Print TypeName(v)            ' prints Integer
Debug.Print TypeName(v * 60)       ' prints Long
Debug.Print TypeName(v * 6000000)  ' prints Double(!)
```

The reason for this can be found in section 5.6.9.3 of the [VBA spec](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-VBAL/%5bMS-VBAL%5d.pdf):

> If one or both operands have a declared type of Variant:
>
> - If the operator’s effective value type is Integer, Long, Single or Double, the operator’s
>   value type is the narrowest type of either Integer, Long or Double such that the
>   operator value is within the valid range of the type. If the result does not fit within
>   Double, runtime error 6 (Overflow) is raised.

Comment: I was about to write that as well but why does re-writing the formula cause VBA to cast the values in a different way.

Comment: @Storax: Updated my answer to address this.

Comment: Hmm, at runtime `time` is an integer. But on the other hand it is `Variant/integer` so you are probably right. PS I tested it as well and yes, you are right.

Comment: @Storax: Exactly. I have added a quote of the relevant part of the VBA spec to my answer. A Variant will even go so far as to promote the multiplication result to a Double if it does not fit in a Long.

Answer (score 1):

As an additon to Heinzi's answer which addresses the OP's question I would like to add that I would add some of the following operators: [CLng, CDbl](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) to make sure that the result will be correct (or better closer to correct :-) )

Instead of `target_time = 1200 * 60 * Time` use `target_time = CDbl(1200) * CDbl(60) * CDbl(Time)`.

Comment: Good idea. Alternatively, you could use `1200.0` or `1200#` instead of `CDbl(1200)`.